# OnDrop event triggers and change data for target control

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a rather simple Question but I couldn't find any Answer.

My setup is the following. I have a simple WinForm application which has one Element(A) which can be dragged. He is starting a DragAndDrop event copy simple Text.

I have a second Window(B) (TextEditor e.g.) which can handle an OnDropEvent and just put in the Text.

Now my case. I want that after Drag is finished of A to B, I can handle an Event to open a new Window where you can type in more Text. This text should then be the Data which should be used by the DragAndDrop-Event.

I hope its clear and there is any good soultion.
Thanks for any help.

Best regards

Comment: Do you have the source code for "Window(**B**)"?  If not, then you can trap the **return value** of [DoDragDrop()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine the "final effect that was performed during the drag-and-drop operation."; many people don't realize this is a **blocking call**.

Comment: I do not have any source code or Control of Window(B).
With the return Value, I can only determine which action was performed in the end. But I can not change the Value for the already performed Action. I need somehow the Part in between. The Action for Dropping is Started but i can still change the Value of the Droped event.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a mechanism to achieve what you want.  Why don't you have the text typed by the user before they perform the drag?

Comment: The user should be able to customize the text further on Operation.
For example, you have a code template of

foreach(var myObject in myObjects)
{
}

and customize it on DragAndDrop to change the names of Objects.

Comment: Right...but if you don't have the source code for App B then I don't think there is an **EASY** way to do this.  You'd have to use some kind of low level injection to intercept the operation.  I don't think you can do this with stock .Net; you'd have to involve some kind of third-party DLL.